# Is there a way to filter User hash by specific value to another of number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, filter

I am working on a project, and I try to filter a hash of users by specific value, is there a way to do that without multi loop?

This is for a personal project, and I try to get a hash of users who are not restricted by one value called `wc_max`.

Here's a sample of the data I get:

I have users data like this:

```
...
[
 {id: 1, wc_max: 5, active: true},
 {id: 2, wc_max: 15, active: true},
 {id: 3, wc_max: 13, active: true},
]
...
```

and array of numbers:

```
...
 [14, 19, 20]
...
```

What I expect is to get a new array of users where the `wc_max` is strictly superior of one of the number's array.
For the example I gave, I expect to get the users with id 2 because its `wc_max` (15) is strictly superior of one array's number (14).

If you have any indication or information to reach this goal or if you need more information let me know.

Comment: what do you mean by strictly superior? is it the nearest highest value of a number? how much nearest number is acceptable 1, 2..?

Comment: If you want to filter two arrays of data based on each of the values in one of the arrays, you are going to need two iterators. It's unclear whether you need to filter by ALL of the numbers in your "array of numbers", or just by a single one?

Answer (score 1):

Get the minimum value of the array and use `select` on user's array:

```rb
> u
 => [{:id=>1, :wc_max=>5, :active=>true}, {:id=>2, :wc_max=>15, :active=>true}, {:id=>3, :wc_max=>13, :active=>true}]
> a
 => [14, 19, 20] 
> min = a.min
> u.select { |i| i[:wc_max] > min }
 => [{:id=>2, :wc_max=>15, :active=>true}]
```